# Can anyone let us know Using Dataflow in Google Cloud Platform, Can we load the CSV file from GCS to BigQuery with out any transformations

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can anyone let us know Using Dataflow in Google Cloud Platform, Can we load the CSV file from GCS to BigQuery with out any transformations

..Just simple load from GCS to BigQuery using Dataflow in Python. If yes, can you provide us....

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible to do without at least 1 transform. The bare minimum transform would be to convert a single row in the CSV (string) to a Python dictionary or a `TableRow` (from BigQuery API), which is required for writing to BigQuery via `BigQuerySink`.

Alternatively, you can simply use the `bq` command line tool to upload a CSV to BigQuery. This is much simpler and can be scheduled by any cron-like application. Note: This solution has different billing implications.

```
bq load --source_format=CSV <destination_table> <data_source_uri> [<table_schema>]
```

bq command line tool reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool

Comment: I have written the code using Dataflow in Python to merge the columns associated with the name as below

Comment: I have written the code using dataflow to merge the columns associated with the name but somehow am not getting right Can you guide me in the right direction

Comment: I have written the code using dataflow to merge the columns associated with the name and write it to BigQuery  but somehow am not getting right Can you guide me in the right direction

Comment: journalsources_schema='JE_Source_Name:STRING,Description:STRING,WordLength;STRING'
# The DoFn to perform on each element in the input PCollection.
class ComputeWordLengthFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    return [len(element)]
word_lengths = lines | beam.ParDo(ComputeWordLengthFn())
The above code has some issues which is not writing into BigQuery with the simple transformation Am just counting the length of the word and writing itto BigQuery Kindly do the needful

Comment: Can you tell us how to create it and what type of functions we have to use to achieve this "The bare minimum transform would be to convert a single row in the CSV (string) to a Python dictionary or a TableRow (from BigQuery API), which is required for writing to BigQuery via BigQuerySink."  I checked multiple transforms on my data but could not able to achieve it?